# Why does font-size increase an input's width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering why setting the `font-size` CSS attribute on an HTML `input` automatically increases its width?

I understand why it increases the height, but I'd like an `input` to remain the same base width when changing the `font-size`.

The reason I ask, is because it is breaking a flex layout I'm building, in which there is an `input`. When I increase the font-size, the `input` completely breaks out of the layout.

Here's a (react) reproduction:

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    maxWidth: 400,
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <input style={{ 'font-size': 20 }} />{' '}
  </div>

  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <input style={{ 'font-size': 50 }} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a clean way to solve this?

Comment: Why not set all the widths the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 100% width or a fixed width on the inputs. Also to get this working in IE, you need to remove `alignItems: 'center'` from the outer most div

```
<div
    style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        maxWidth: 400,
        padding: 20,
    }}
>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <input style={{ 'font-size': 20, width: "100%", boxSizing: "border-box" }} />
    </div>

    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <input style={{ 'font-size': 50, width: "100%", boxSizing: "border-box" }} />
    </div>
</div>
```

For firefox you have to wrap the input in a container and apply `flex: 1 1 auto;` to the container.

Hope that helps

Comment: That's the right answer! I don't understand it though, why doesn't `width: 100%` not override the flex-box pattern? i.e. become literally 100% width of the parent? What does it mean in this case?

Comment: The reason it doesnt work in firefox is because it does override the flex box values and becomes 100% width of the parent so you create a wrapper which uses flex to grow in the space available. Why this works in Chrome and IE I'm not sure sorry. Hopefully someone else can answer this?

Answer (score 9):

`<input>` tag is one of the [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) and they often have intrinsic dimensions.

In flexbox you can override the intrinsic size by adding:

```
input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Or, give it a smaller [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-size) than the default value `20`:

```
<input size="1">
```

Then set the desire size by using `flex` / `flex-grow` / `flex-basis`, or `width` as needed.

Comment: I think this is the better answer!